# Using Orderby and meta_value to order natural/alphanumerical

Tags: custom-post-types, posts, order, sort, meta-value

I added a custom column for a custom post type. Then I put it to be the 3th column, and now I want to sort it alphanumerical. 
I use this action : `add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'manage_wp_posts_be_qe_pre_get_posts', 1 );`
I write this fuction:

```
   function manage_wp_posts_be_qe_pre_get_posts( $query ) {
   if ( $query->is_main_query() && ( $orderby = $query->get( 'orderby' ) ) ) { 
      switch( $orderby ) {
         case 'Rif':
            $query->set( 'meta_key', 'riferimento' );
            $query->set( 'orderby', 'meta_value meta_value_num');
            break;
      }

   }
}
```

but it doesn't works. 
It returns me always :

[image]

But I want first CA3 CA5 and then CA10 .... 
I tried also to cast with LENGTH() or similr things, but nothing to do..

Comment: Ordering by `meta_value_num` only works when the meta value is an integer.

Comment: @WebElaine yes i know

Answer (score 0):

The orderby argument is limited by what is possible in MySQL, and it's not good at natural alphanumeric sorting like you describe. Possible options include:

- Rewriting the values with leading zeros, e.g. "CA05"
- Creating a separate "Sort Order" column that just stores an integer, and ordering by that.
- Separating the letters and numbers into two separate fields. Then writing a more complex query to sort by two different meta values:

  ```
  $query->set( 'meta_query', array(
      'relation' => 'AND',
      'letter_clause' => array(
          'key' => 'letter',
      ),
      'number_clause' => array(
          'key' => 'number',
          'type' => 'NUMERIC'
      )
  );
  $query->set( 'orderby', array(
      'letter_clause' => 'ASC',
      'number_clause' => 'ASC'
  );
  ```

  More info on that syntax here: https://www.billerickson.net/wp-query-sort-by-meta/